# how to link 2 python scripts for a same project

Tags: python, web, project

I am making a web project, for this i have summery scripts and crawling scripts now I want to link both these two scripts together so that my both scripts work automatically for a single project.

For example: I am using PyCharm.

If i have one file is Summery.Py and second file is crawler.Py both have separate modules. I want to link them a one program

Comment: Link them ? what does that mean ? If you meant to use features from both files (say functions), you could import one or the other from either of the files and use the required functionality

Comment: Use import simply both on a third python module or import one to other. Can't you use `import <your-python-module>`

Comment: i have many fucntions

Answer (score 1):

This is handled through the `import` functionality of Python. You can do something like:

crawler.py

```
from Summery import * # will run Summery.py and load all global variables and functions
```

Or use the more apt

```
from Summery import myFunction # get just one function
```

It works both ways too

Summery.py

```
from crawler import * # you don't include the '.py'
```

If they are in different directories, you do

```
from MainPyCharmFolder.SubFolder.DeepFolder.Summery import myFunction
```

Which enables you to navigate your folder structure

Comment: thanks for this quick response.. actually i have many function in both python files because both are two different modules of my project .. so its imposible for me to import all functions.. then what should i do ?

Comment: @ZainnomanFarooq You can say `from MainPyCharmFolder.SubFolder.DeepFolder.Summery import myFunction, otherFunction, bigFunction, myOtherFunction` on one line or just copy and paste it for as many functions as you need. You can also consider `from Summery import *` if you are ok with having lots of global variables and do not plan on distributing your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `import` to make the functions in one script callable in the other.

E.g. Within crawler.py add `import Summery` and call the functions within normally.

Comment: thanks for this quick response.. actually i have many function in both python files because both are two different modules of my project .. so its imposible for me to import all functions.. then what should i do ?

Comment: You can try `from Summery import [insert function name here], [another function], [another]`